# Minikube: access dashboard from host

Tags: minikube

minikube on a vm, vm is installed on windows10.

how to access minikube's dashboard from windows10?

I heard and doing some investigate about `nodeport` but still asking.

Comment: Are you trying to access the dashboard from same host of vm? Also, is `minikube` cli available on ur PC?

Answer (score -1):

I guess the simplest way to do this is kubectl proxy. 
You can find an instruction in official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#accessing-the-dashboard-ui)

Comment: Unlucky, from your link: `The UI can only be accessed from the machine where the command is executed`

Comment: From your question I assumed that you want to access dashboard from the same host where minikube runs. If not, please be a little more specific about your issue.